# How to create and use a refresh token for Azure AD

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, active-directory

I currently have an Azure website that is hooked up to an Azure Active Directory and users can currently sign in using this.

However, the access token that is created as part of the login process only enables users to remain logged in for one hour. After some research I have found that this problem can be fixed with the introduction of a Refresh Token, which will enable the user to be logged in for longer.

The problem now is that i cannot find any code on how to actually create and use this refresh token in my project. Below is the library and code that I am using to communicate with  Active Directory:

```
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory;

    public class Startup {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {
            var config = new HttpConfiguration();
            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }

        private void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app) {
            app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
                new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions {
                    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {
                        ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AudienceUri"]
                    },
                    Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureADTenant"]
                });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at [active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-oauth2-useridentity](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-oauth2-useridentity) particularly how it utilizes the TokenDbCache in combination with ADAL to store refreshtokens.

When you configure ADAL AuthenticationContext with a TokenCache, ADAL will automatically try to retrieve a refresh token from the cache, if available and valid.